# hroizontal scrollbar not displaying when autosizemode set to fill in datagridview

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, scrollbar, autosize

I have a datagridview in my windows forms.
The no of columns are dynamically generated.

I set the last column's **AutoSizeMode to fill** and it makes the columns fill the grid.

But this fails to display the horizontal scrollbar when the last column contents exceed the column width.

Comment: Did you set ScrollBars property of DGV to Both or Hotyzontal?

Comment: Have a look here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewautosizecolumnmode(v=vs.110).aspx maybe it will be helpfull

Comment: It seem that it is a normal and expected behavior, because it's no need in horizntal scroll, because the column width is adjusted to DGV width!